# deleting a node passed by reference in c

Tags: c, linked-list

please I am trying to delete a node passed by value and returned by the function but the head is passed by reference. I tried this code but the compiler complain at the: *head = *head->next;

here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


typedef struct nody student;


struct nody{

    char name[20];

    double gpa;

    student *next;

};

student* deletefirstlist(student **head, student *nn);

int main(){

    student *head, *node, *w;

    node = (student*) malloc(sizeof(student));
    gets(node->name);
    node->gpa=3.6;
    node->next=NULL;

    head = node;

    node = (student*) malloc(sizeof(student));
    gets(node->name);
    node->gpa=3.7;
    node->next=head;

    head = node;

    w = head;
    while(w!=NULL){
        printf("%s %lf\n\n", w->name, w->gpa);
        w=w->next;
    }
    node = deletefirstnode(&head,  node);

    while(w!=NULL){
        printf("%s %lf\n\n", w->name, w->gpa);
        w=w->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

student* deletefirstlist(student **head, student *nn){


    nn = *head;
    *head = *head->next; // the problem is here
    nn->next=NULL;

    return nn;
}
```

thanks a million

Comment: `*head->next` --> `(*head)->next`

Comment: I tried to do the *head = nn-> next;

Comment: and it worked. is it right?

Comment: In that context `(*head)->next` and `nn-> next` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

From the quoted code I understand that you create a list with a head and a linked node and then you try to delete the first(head) node. If it is so, then
your code has to be corrected to the following:

```
   #include<stdio.h>


    typedef struct nody student;


     struct nody{

       char name[20];

       double gpa;

       student *next;

     };

   student *deletefirstnode(student *head, student *nn);

   int main(){

    student *head, *node, *w;

    node = (student*) malloc(sizeof(student));
    gets(node->name);
    node->gpa=3.6;
    node->next=NULL;

    head = node;

    node = (student*) malloc(sizeof(student));
    gets(node->name);
    node->gpa=3.7;
    head->next=node;
    node->next=NULL;

    //  head->next = node (The first node is the head node)

    w = head;
    while(w!=NULL){
     printf("%s %lf\n\n", w->name, w->gpa);
     w=w->next;
    }
    node = deletefirstnode(head,  node);
    free(head); //to free up the memory of the old first node
    w=node;  //reset w to point to the new First node of the list
    while(w!=NULL){
     printf("%s %lf\n\n", w->name, w->gpa);
     w=w->next;
     }
    return 0; 
   }

   student *deletefirstnode(student *head, student *nn){
      nn = head->next;
      return nn;
   }
```

Hope these help.

Comment: Thanks a lot it does help! just about the free(head); statement. do we have to do it because as I know if we lose the head the linked list is lost.
correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Overall correction sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //need this

typedef struct nody student;

struct nody{
    char name[20];
    double gpa;
    student *next;
};

student* deletefirstlist(student **head, student *nn);

int main(){
    student *head, *node, *w;

    node = (student*) malloc(sizeof(student));//casting is not necessary in C.
    *node->name = 0;
    //gets has already been abolished.
    while(1 != scanf("%19[^\n]%*c", node->name)){
        printf("input name\n");
        scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");
    }
    node->gpa=3.6;
    node->next=NULL;

    head = node;

    node = (student*) malloc(sizeof(student));
    *node->name = 0;
    while(1 != scanf("%19[^\n]%*c", node->name)){
        printf("input name\n");
        scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");
    }
    node->gpa=3.7;
    node->next=head;

    head = node;

    w = head;
    while(w != NULL){
        printf("%s %lf\n\n", w->name, w->gpa);
        w = w->next;
    }
    node = deletefirstlist(&head,  NULL);//The argument node is not necessary substantially. also function name is typo.

    free(node);

    w = head;//you forgot this
    while(w != NULL){
        printf("%s %lf\n\n", w->name, w->gpa);
        w = w->next;
    }
    //free rest
    return 0;
}

student* deletefirstlist(student **head, student *nn){
    nn = *head;
    if(*head){//NOT NULL
        *head = (*head)->next; // *head->next meant *(head->next)
        nn->next=NULL;
    }

    return nn;
}
```

Comment: `"%19[^\n]%*c"` does not work if they press enter without typing any other characters

Comment: Yes, Of course.  You can grant a check for that. Or Enter a name where you should enter a name.　:D

Answer (score 0):

As far as compiler complaining is considered, this will fix it

```
*head = (*head)->next;
```

But there are other problems with the code like you are not freeing the memory for the deleted node returned by your function :

```
node = deletefirstnode(&head,  node);
free(node); //missing
w=head; //w still points to the deleted node, point it to the new head 
while(w!=NULL){
```

BLUEPIXY's code takes care of all these problems.

If you use C++ for the same, might I suggest using string for name, then you can easily take input as

```
getline(cin,name);
```

Also you can use your function as

```
student* deletefirstlist(student*& head, student *nn);
```

There wont be any need to use indirection then. You can simply do :

```
student* deletefirstlist (student* &head, student *nn) {
nn = head;
if (head) {
    head = head->next; // *head->next meant *(head->next)
    nn->next=NULL;
}

return nn;
}
```

and call as :

```
node = deletefirstlist(head, node);
```

You will need to change the fn declaration too :

```
student* deletefirstlist(student *&head, student *nn);
```